# viewing stackTrace in the UI?

Tags: google-cloud-trace

When i try to add a stackTrace to my spans, i get the following results:

1. Adding stackTrace to a parent span results in an empty "Callstack" section in the UI ([parent stackTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8NcJ.png))
2. Adding stackTrace to a child span results in a "/stackTrace" attribute in the UI. The attribute value is an unformatted json dump that's pretty hard to read ([child stackTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPmuy.png))

Is this the result of calling the API incorrectly or is this what i should expect from this feature?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: @GhostCat the pictures are not of code, there's nothing to transcribe in them, and no text to index in them. My question is about the UI of a service, an image seems very much warranted.